# Rego - Pass if value in set is in allowed_values set

Tags: opa, open-policy-agent, rego

I'm trying to have a policy pass if a value in `input_set` matches a value in `allow_values`

The below policy example is also here if you'd like to modify it easier - https://play.openpolicyagent.org/

I'm sure that I'm not understanding the use of `some` but at this point I'm just a bit too turned around and there is probably a better way to have a check like this.

```
package sometesting
import future.keywords

# Check these values against `allow_values`
input_set := {"b-phone", "a-pad", "a-car"}

# If these values are in the set - don't fail the policy
allow_values := {"b-phone", "a-pad"}

# I can check the values individually like below
policy_1[result] {

    not "b-phone" in input_set
    not "a-pad" in input_set

    true
    
    result := "policy_failed"
}

# However when I try to use some, it doesn't seem to pass the policy when they match
policy_2[result] {

    some value in input_set
    not value in allow_values
    # I thought this should return : 
    # true
    # false
    # false

    true
    
    result := "policy_failed"
}

# I was expecting it to essentially end up like this and fail if one item in the some statement was false, however I seem to be a bit confused on this.
policy_3[result] {


    true
    false
    false

    true
    
    result := "policy_failed"
}
```

EDIT****
I think this will work ( I don't have enough rep to add the answer )

```
policy_2[result] {

    in_allowed_values

    true
    
    result := "policy_failed"
}


in_allowed_values := false {
    contains(allow_values[_], input_values[_])
} else = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that set intersection would be the best way to do this:

```rb
package sometesting

import future.keywords

input_set := {"b-phone", "a-pad", "a-car"}

allow_values := {"b-phone", "a-pad"}

policy contains result if {
    input_set & allow_values == set()

    result := "policy_failed"
}
```

Here we test if the input set and the allow_values have any elements in common by computing the intersection. If this set of common elements is empty, then it's a policy violation.

Comment: Thanks!

Is there any benefit to doing it this way as opposed to the way I figured out? ( that may or may not work with more testing... 

`contains(allow_values[_], input_set[_])`

Comment: I'd expect that set intersection should be more performant but I don't have the data to hand. It'd also count as more idiomatic. foo[_] style is discouraged, for example: https://docs.styra.com/regal/rules/idiomatic/use-in-operator

Comment: I appreciate the help here and I've created a separate question that's a bit more refined as to what I'm trying to accomplish. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78162514/rego-pass-if-resource-tag-value-matches-exception-tag-values

If you have time I'd really appreciate a quick review of that. I have a 'working' solution but it's probably done in a rough way.

Comment: Hey, I am out for the rest of the week. You might want to try this one in the OPA slack! http://slack.openpolicyagent.org