# Rego - Pass if resource tag value matches exception tag values

Tags: opa, open-policy-agent, rego

I'm trying to allow specific resources to pass a check if their tag values match an array of values.

I originally asked this question - [Rego - Pass if value in set is in allowed_values set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78156137/rego-pass-if-value-in-set-is-in-allowed-values-set) - However that simple example didn't exactly translate to the problem I had when trying to evaluate the tags.

I've created this 'working' example and would like to know how it can be done in a more proper way.
https://play.openpolicyagent.org/#L8

```
package tagtesting
import future.keywords


passing_1_resource_tags := {
    "Environment": "dev",
    "Name": "name1",
    "Test": "test"
}

passing_2_resource_tags := {
    "Environment": "dev",
    "Name": "name1",
    "Test": "test"
}

failing_resource_tags := {
    "Environment": "xxx",
    "Name": "xxx",
    "Test": "test"
}


exception_tags := {
    "Environment" : ["dev", "int"],
    "Name" : ["name1"]
}

tag_exception_check(resource_tags) := {
    item |         
        # Check if resource tag key matches for exception tag key
        some key in object.keys(resource_tags)
        key in object.keys(exception_tags)
        # Check matching keys for resource_tag value against exception values
        resource_tags[key] in exception_tags[key]
        item := key
}

passing_1_policy[result] {
    tag_exception_check(passing_1_resource_tags) == set()
    true   
    result := "policy_failed"
}

passing_2_policy[result] {
    tag_exception_check(passing_2_resource_tags) == set()
    true   
    result := "policy_failed"
}

failing_policy[result] {  
    tag_exception_check(failing_resource_tags) == set()
    true   
    result := "policy_failed"
}
```

Output :

```
{
    "exception_tags": {
        "Environment": [
            "dev",
            "int"
        ],
        "Name": [
            "name1"
        ]
    },
    "failing_policy": [
        "policy_failed"
    ],
    "failing_resource_tags": {
        "Environment": "xxx",
        "Name": "xxx",
        "Test": "test"
    },
    "passing_1_policy": [],
    "passing_1_resource_tags": {
        "Environment": "dev",
        "Name": "name1",
        "Test": "test"
    },
    "passing_2_policy": [],
    "passing_2_resource_tags": {
        "Environment": "dev",
        "Name": "name1",
        "Test": "test"
    }
}
```